# Using Android Studio default search icon for searchView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-image, android-icons

Can't seem to find the right search icon for the searchView for my actionBar. Does Android Studio even offer a non-bad one or do I have to create my own?

Here's what's offered in Android Studio: ( I want to have all white icons)

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
```

[image]

This search icon doesn't work for me.

===============================================

Here's another Android Studio icon that won't work with my white icons:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
```

[image]

==============================================

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
```

The final Android Studio available search icon from Image Asset Folder --> Clip Art. It's finally a white icon but it's positioned higher than the settings icon. Don't know why.

[image]

I need a white icon like the last one but to be in the same position as the settings Icon. Is there any way to lower icon without making it look odd on other phones? Do I have to create my own icon and if so, what sizes? Why does Android Studio put the white search Icon so high up compared to others?

Comment: check https://material.io/icons/

Comment: Are these open source?

Comment: Yes you can use them in your app

Comment: Whatever, I don't find in Android Studio, i'll certainly consider using these material icons, thank you.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also access this list of icons in https://material.io/icons/
 from Android Studio

[image]

[image]

Comment: My 3rd and white search icon above is from Image Asset folder.

Comment: Do You have layout for the action bar ?

Comment: Yeah I Know , Try To Download the search icon from the website and use it with size 48Dp and check

Comment: You can add custom view for action bar 
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(YOUR VIEW, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);

Comment: Alright, thank you, i'll give it a try. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You are welcome :)  , If it worked don't forget to vote up :)